# Using javax.tools.ToolProvider from a custom classloader?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, casting, classloader

It seems to be impossible to use `javax.tools.ToolProvider` from a custom classloader as required by Ant or Webstart: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6548428

`javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` loads `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` into a URLClassLoader whose parent is the system classloader. The API does not seem to allow users to specify a parent classloader.

**How can one use `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` from a custom classloader?**

For example:

- Ant loads `MyParserTask`
- `MyParserTask` parses Java source-code
- `MyParserTask` is loaded by `AntClassLoader` that delegates to the system classloader
- `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` is loaded by `URLClassLoader` thast delegates to the system classloader

At a later point, `MyParserTask` invokes:

```
javax.tools.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(...);
com.sun.source.util.JavacTask javacTask = (com.sun.source.util.JavacTask) task;
javacTask.parse().next().accept(visitor, unused); // parsing happens here
```

- Seeing how the two classes reside on separate classloaders, there doesn't seem to be a way for `MyParserTask` to interact with `JavacTask` without getting `ClassCastException` errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem.  I'm using a custom ant task to scan the AST for certain kinds of method invocations.  My solution, which may not be appropriate for you, was to instantiate the compiler myself instead of using the ToolProvider.

I replaced

`JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();`

with

`JavaCompiler compiler = (JavaCompiler)Class.forName("com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool").newInstance();`

This certainly isn't future proof or safe in all environments, but it is an option depending on your needs.  If someone else has a better way around using ToolProvider in custom Ant tasks please share.

Answer (score 0):

This problem frequently occurs with OSGi. Some people have come up with "bridge class loaders", see for example [this article](http://www.dynamicjava.org/articles/osgi-matters/non-osgi-application-object-accessing) (which probably only bridges interfaces, not subclasses, so maybe you cannot use it directly).

If there are only a few methods you want to invoke on the "foreign" object, you can also get away with reflection:

```
 javax.tools.CompilationTask task;
 task.getClass().getMethod("someMethodInTheSubclassThatICannotSee").invoke("a");
```

Building on the reflection idea, maybe a scripting language is helpful, too (Groovy, Beanshell, JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that the same class loaded by two different class loaders is a different type and never the twain shall be cross assignable.  That's it.  You have to have both classes use the same class loader to get the shared class.

This would usually be a result of violating the pre-emptive deferring of class loading to a ClassLoader's parent.  Simply put, any class loader **must** first ask it's parent to load a class before it attempts to load it itself.  Doing otherwise results in all sorts of "interesting" problems.

In your specific example, since A invoked B, it was B's class loader that failed to delegate to it's parent, since if A can see the target class, B's class loader did not need to load it, given that A invoked B and therefore A's class loader or some ancestor thereof loaded B.

Comment: I rewrote the question to focus on CompilationTask. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems I had to load the tools.jar When I discovered that a sub class was not getting loaded. details in this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619179/webappclassloader-loadclass-cannot-find-class-at-runtime
As I mention this may not be a good solution as we are trying to tinker with the classloading through a program. found some notes here useful as well
http://easternlights-wisdomtree.blogspot.in/2013/02/classloading-blues-part1.html