# System.getProperty("java.class.path") does not show "WEB-INF/lib" and the including jars

Tags: java, compilation, classpath

```
String CompilePath = "abc.java";
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
System.setProperty("java.class.path", classpath + ";" + LocalMachine.home + "WebContent/WEB-INF/lib");
int result = compiler.run(null, null, null, CompilePath);
```

The above runs fine when executed as a JUnit test since all the `jars` required for compiling the `abc.java` file. But when the same code is being run in as server, it fails to find the required `jar` files. The output of `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` is 
`E:\apache-tomcat-7.0.4\bin\bootstrap.jar;E:\apache-tomcat-7.0.4\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\lib\tools.jar`

So, my question is how do I make the compiler refer to the jar files from the WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: How are you packaging (generating the WAR) in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way you are setting the java.class.path system property is asking for trouble - better not do that. **More elegant approach would be to use the `-classpath` option to pass in the custom classpath.** See [How do I use JDK6 ToolProvider and JavaCompiler with the context classloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274474/how-do-i-use-jdk6-toolprovider-and-javacompiler-with-the-context-classloader) for details.

Also this question can be useful reference: [Using javax.tools.ToolProvider from a custom classloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315719/how-to-interact-with-javax-tools-toolprovider-outside-the-system-classloader)

---

As to building the actual classpath, you could **cast the context classloader to `URLClassLoader`** and get files from those URLs (as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274474/how-do-i-use-jdk6-toolprovider-and-javacompiler-with-the-context-classloader/665896#665896)).

Or you could use [ServletContext](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).`getRealPath(String)` and **build the entire classpath by hand**:

```
ServletConfig cfg = ...; //obtained in Servlet.init(ServletConfig) method
ServletContex ctx = cfg.getServletContext();
String realWebInfPath = ctx.getRealPath("WEB-INF/lib");
//TODO use the realWebInfPath to create a File object and iterate over all JAR files
```

**Warning**: both approaches **ONLY** work if web application is expanded (not WAR file). If it is not expanded, you are out of luck.

Comment: Although the solutions you mentioned seem useful, I found executing a batch script instead, wherein I can easily pass the classpath was a much easy way. I know this is not an ideal way by any means.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot depend on java.class.path to be set to anything in particular.

Java establishes this variable when it launches the entire JVM containing your servlet container. As it creates many different class loaders for many different other purposes, it does not change it. It cannot. There is only one value of java.class.path for the entire process, but there can be many different webapps, and indeed many different class loaders inside each webapp.

You will need your own explicit configuration mechanism to communicate the class path for this sort of compilation stuff, and to use getRealPath to construct the pathnames.

Comment: Now I understand that it does not make sense to change the classpath dynamically. But since the plain old java objects that are being referred by the servlets can successfully access all the jar files present in WEB-INF/lib directory, why does this path not appear in the classpath by default?

Comment: Because the classpath contains the jars themselves, not some directory that happens to contain the jars.

Comment: How does the explicit configuration mechanism works? Can you please refer me to some examples of the same? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd follow the breadcrumbs in the other answer for your specific issue. If you can just push your current class loader into this compiler thing to use, you don't need to deal with all of this.

Answer (score 2):

> So, my question is how do I make the compiler refer to the jar files from the WEB-INF/lib directory?

Provide that the webapp's WAR is expanded, you should be able to programmatically create a classpath string that corresponds to what the web container gives you.  It is "simply" a matter of duplicating the effective class search path that the web container uses.

However, I suspect that passing a "classpath" argument to the compiler, explicitly or via the System properties is the wrong approach.  I found the following in [this IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jcomp/index.html).

> Compiling Java source requires the following components:
>
> - A classpath, from which the compiler
>     can resolve library classes. The
>     compiler classpath is typically
>     composed of an ordered list of file
>     system directories and archive files
>     (JAR or ZIP files) that contain
>     previously compiled .class files. The
>     classpath is implemented by a
>     JavaFileManager that manages multiple
>     source and class JavaFileObject
>     instances and the ClassLoader passed
>     to the JavaFileManager constructor. ...

So it would seem that the correct approach is to just grab the relevant classloader object and pass it to the JavaFileManager constructor.

Comment: "So it would seem that the correct approach is to just grab the relevant classloader object and pass it to the JavaFileManager constructor." - given that JavaFileManager is an interface, I do not see how you can pass anything to its "constructor". If this approach seems possible, could you provide a code sample for illustrative purposes? ;-)

Comment: ok, JavaFileManager should actually read FileManagerImpl and it is given in the referenced develperWorks article (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jcomp/index.html). This article seems to be most useful so far, seems to nicely solve the issue of using already existing classpath object.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are using ANT to build your WAR file. You need to do something like below to include jars under WEB-INF/lib in your WAR. Modify the directory structure as it fits your app directory structure.

```
<war warfile="yourApp.war" webxml="WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="yourWarDir">
                <include name="**/*.jsp"/>  
                <include name="**/include/**"/>
            </fileset>
            <include name="WEB-INF/lib/*"/>
            <include name="WEB-INF/classes/**"/>

</war>
```

Comment: I have a feeling that he is not asking for instructions on how to include JAR files in web application.

Comment: I'm not using ant to build. Eclipse does all the stuff in the web project.

Comment: @Neeme Praks - His problem lies in packaging the app. He is relying on the server classpath to find jar files that he includes in WEB-INF/lib folder. What does that tell you?

Comment: @CoolBeans that tells me that he should use some other way to put together his classpath, as suggested by other answers. Your answer seems to suggest that he is not putting his JAR files in WAR. The fact if he is building a WAR or not is not even important, he could also run the webapp in-place, as "exploded" webapp.

Comment: So I am approaching it this way. If he is building a WAR file and WEB-INF/lib is included in that WAR file, then his problem is solved right? However, if he is running in place then he has to look for the classpath in a different way. He said he runs it in a server, which leads me to believe he is building a WAR file and deploying it to a web server.

Comment: Even if he is building a WAR file and WEB-INF/lib is included, his problem is not solved - he does not know how to use that webapp classloader to compile his classes using JavaCompiler. That's why this is not a "packaging problem" - packaging does not really matter.