# How to provide an interface to JavaCompiler when compiling a source file dynamically?

Tags: java, dynamic, runtime, compilation, classloader

I'm trying to compile and load a class at runtime, without knowing the package of the class. I do know that the class should comply with an interface, and the location of the source, (and hence the class name). I'm trying the following:

```
/* Compiling source */
File root = new File("scripts");
File sourceFile = new File(root, "Test.java");
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
compiler.run(null, null, null, sourceFile.getPath());
```

where the Test.java file looks something like

```
import foo.Itest;
public class Test implements Itest{
...
}
```

And I get a `cannot find symbol symbol  : class Itest` error from the compiler. How do I **provide the compiler with the interface** (which has already been loaded) to avoid this error?

**[EDIT - RESOLVED]:** The error came from the fact the the interface was `ITest` and the source referred to an `Itest` interface.

Comment: Motherfriggin typo! The interface loaded is `ITest`, not `Itest`.

Comment: If a Moderator sees this post and feels that it should be deleted, I'm happy with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you dynamically compile and load external java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes)

Comment: Probably related, Mostly the same goal. It's somewhat the the other way round though, by 4 *years*. I'll mark the other as a possible duplicate.

Comment: https://medium.com/@davutgrbz/the-need-history-c91c9d38ec9

Answer (score 3):

It seems likely that the `compiler.run()` is running externally and needs the class path to be set.  Have you tried to pass it a suitable class path setting using the last parameter `args` to the `run()` call?  Perhaps that's why `ToolProvider.getSystemToolClassLoader()`.

This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274474/how-do-i-use-jdk6-toolprovider-and-javacompiler-with-the-context-classloader) might also help you.

Comment: Thanks jowierun, It turns out it was a much more mundane error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but, as mentioned by @Phil [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274474/how-do-i-use-jdk6-toolprovider-and-javacompiler-with-the-context-classloader), you could try to pass a classpath argument in your `compiler.run` method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered generating your class with [javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) or something like that?