# Java - distributed object logic: server as the store / client as the worker

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**TL;DR**: I have a requirement for distributing business logic at runtime between a server and multiple remote clients running Selenium WebDriver .

I have looked at object serialization, RMI, downloading JARs on-the-fly, Selenese through Java and Selenium Grid.

---

**Detail**: Multiple remote clients are expected to poll a queue via JMS over the Internet to obtain an Order to go do some work on a given website. Each client will start Selenium WebDriver, traverse through that website *in a manner that is not pre-defined (or only in very abstract terms) prior to client runtime*, then go back to polling the queue until called again.

The challenge is that neither the website nor the exact traversing steps will be known to the client in advance. I can define the abstract steps / methods in advance *on the server* but the client will depend on some kind of downloaded data to obtain the list of Selenium commands precisely. There is also some looping required in those steps (`repeat until...`).

For instance, if we define `void login()` for example1.com:

1. Click 'username' field
2. Send keys 'username'
3. Click 'password' field
4. Send keys 'password'
5. Click 'submit'

Whereas for example2.com `void login()` would be:

1. Click 'login' box
2. Wait for 'username' field to appear
3. Click 'username' field
4. Click 'continue'
5. etc.

**Researched**:

- **Serialization**: Will transfer only object variables, not object logic.
- **RMI**: Object logic is executed on the server, not the client, so it cannot interact with the client's Selenium instance.
- **Downloading JARs on the fly**: Possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002462/how-can-i-write-a-java-application-that-can-update-itself-at-runtime) and less optimistically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime). Are these realistic?
- **Selenese**: Probably cannot be run directly under Java. Might be possible with [selenese-runner-java](https://github.com/vmi/selenese-runner-java) but this appears to be command-line only, which would limit interaction with client software and therefore functionality
- **Selenium Grid**: Node (client) must be connected to Hub (server) at all times, which cannot be guaranteed

How can I distribute business logic from server to client at runtime in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare an interface `SeleniumRunner` with a generic Selenium run method like that.

```
public void runSelenium(WebDriver driver);
```

As described in [How to provide an interface to JavaCompiler when compiling a source file dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447359/how-to-provide-an-interface-to-javacompiler-when-compiling-a-source-file-dynamic) you can transfer source files to your client an compile them at runtime. The class has to implement the above mentioned interface.

```
File sourceFile = new File("SeleniumClass1234.java");
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
compiler.run(null, null, null, sourceFile.getPath());
...

SeleniumRunner sr = (SeleniumRunner) Class.forName("SeleniumClass1234").newInstance();
sr.runSelenium(driver);
```

Or you can transfer jar files to your clients and load them at runtime as described in your second link [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime). You will need the interface here as well. Otherwise your solution will contain a lot of reflection and additional configuration setup to find and use the right methods containing your logic.